# $resource save working with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method in an asp.net MVC controller, which my angular code is trying to call:

```
       [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEducationList(List<InventoryGroupModel> inventoryEduList, int examId)
    {
        var listOfInventories = _examService.AddEduInventoryGroup(inventoryEduList);
        return Json(listOfInventories);
    }
```

My angular code to call this is:

```
            saveEduList: function (inventoryEduList, examId) {
            return $resource('/mysite/Setup/SaveEducationList',
                { inventoryEduList: '@inventoryEduList', examId: '@examId' }, {
                save: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    isArray: true
                }
            }).save(inventoryEduList, examId);
        }
```

When this angular method is called, I can see in Chrome's debugger that both the inventoryEduList and examId are populated, but whenever the call to the MVC method is made, nothing happens.  Fiddler shows that it was calling method just passing in the examId, nothing else.  Is there anyway to pass both parameters?

Comment: create a class with List<InventoryGroupModel> inventoryEduList, int examId and pass into the SaveEducationList such as SaveEducationList(aclass avalue)

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan so save can only take 1 parameter?

Comment: yes, angular post a single object, so mvc try to map the object with paramater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following...

create a new class

```
public class SaveParam {
public List<InventoryGroupModel> InventoryEduList {get;set;}
public int ExamId {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEducationList(SaveParam param)
    {
        var listOfInventories = _examService.AddEduInventoryGroup(param.InventoryEduList );
        return Json(listOfInventories);
    }
```

hope this help